# Basis ambiguity for bipartite entanglement

Tags: quantum-entanglement

I am reading

> Decoherence, einselection, and the quantum origins of the classical

from Wojciech Hubert Zurek

And he says at some point that for a three partite quantum system there is no basis ambiguity when we write an entangled state.

Basis ambiguity is the following. I consider two systems $A$ and $B$ entangled in the following state :

$$  \frac{|0_A \rangle |0_B \rangle + |1_A \rangle |1_B \rangle}{\sqrt{2}} $$

Where $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ are z-spin $\pm 1 $ eigenvectors

As I have the following property :

$$ \frac{|0_A \rangle |0_B \rangle + |1_A \rangle |1_B \rangle}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{|+_A \rangle |+_B \rangle + |-_A \rangle |-_B \rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$

With $|\pm\rangle = \frac{|0 \rangle \pm |1 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$.

The ambiguity is from what I understood : I can either say that my systems are maximally correlated in the $|0\rangle, |1\rangle$ basis, or in the $|+\rangle, |-\rangle$ basis.

Why isn't it possible to have such basis ambiguity in general for a three-partite entangled system ? Is there an easy way to see it ?

Comment: Allright, the answer is actually non trivial and can be found in this paper : https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.49.4213

Comment: Then write an answer!

Comment: @norbert schuch well right now i just know there is a non trivial answer for the question in the given paper. When i will have read it and understood it i will write an answer !

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/289256/does-uniqueness-of-the-triorthogonal-decomposition-make-quantum-measurement-obje I have to say, I still don't quite get it and maybe someone will post a clearer answer here!

Comment: @user1936752 thanks for the link